# How to use enums in C safely?

Tags: c, enums

consider the following example:

```
typedef enum {Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday} Day;
void DoSomething(Day day){
//some code
}
```

The problem is that the following code complies: `DoSomething(74)`. So how can I check in DoSomething that my parameter is really a Day?
(relying on numbers won't work because if I change my enum like that `Sunday=7` .... ,I want it to work too, and checking `if(day==Sunday || day ==...)` looks inefficient).

Comment: `enum` in C++11 are type-safe.http://stackoverflow.com/a/12581154/1809377

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is you can't.

The long answer is you can try to put a "minimum" and a "maximum" member, and check that the value falls in the range between the two... or some other similar trick.

Comment: But if you check day >=0 && day <=6 and then change your enum to Sunday=7... , your code won't works.

Comment: @Sefi: You would do `enum {First,Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Last} Day;` and then check if `First < day && day < Last`.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef enum {Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday, Last} Day;
void DoSomething(Day day){
   // if day < Last ...
}
```

Comment: If you're going to go this route, I think it's much better to just have `Last` (without an assignment) and then check using `day < last`, since that makes the construct less brittle. Otherwise you can add something after `Saturday` and fail to update `Last`, causing breakage.

Answer (score 0):

You could put a switch statement in your DoSomething.

```
switch(day){
case Day.Monday:
     // something
    break
...
default: 
    // ignore or something
```

Answer (score 0):

If you write DoSomething(74) statement in your code modern compiler generate warning saying DoSomething expect enum but integer is passed.

But if you are passing a value from user input where any value can be passed to DoSomething() then you will have to take care as other advised.