# Is it possible to add to class scope in C++?

Tags: c++, c++03

Using C++03, consider the following code:

```
enum compare_status {
    no_match,
    match,
    partial_match,
    error
};

// Interface
class IOBuffInterface {
 public:
    virtual ~IOBuffInterface() {}
    virtual compare_status compare(uint8_t* start, unsigned n) = 0;
};

// Object
class IOBuff: public IOBuffInterface {
 public:
    virtual ~IOBuffInterface() {}
    virtual compare_status compare(uint8_t* start, unsigned n) = 0;
};
```

Is it possible to have the `compare_status` enum to be part of the `IOBuff` scope, so it would look like this externally `IOBuff::compare_status`, the problem is it is required by the `IOBuffInterface` class which precedes the IOBuff class.  Are there any solutions for this?

EDIT:  n.m. provided the answer in the comment, **in C++03 You Cannot**

Comment: Make it a part of `IOBuffInterface`.

Comment: `virtual ~IOBuffInterface() {}` typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it a part of `IOBuffInterface`, because that's what it really is.

Any class inheriting from `IOBuffInterface` will need `compare_status`. It is rather unclear why its definition should be contained in one specific chind of `IOBuffInterface`, rather than made available to all siblings equally.

Comment: Basically the answer to my question based on all the input is *in C++03 you cannot*.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a typedef to `IOBuff`:

```
class IOBuff: public IOBuffInterface {
 public:
    typedef ::compare_status compare_status;
    virtual ~IOBuffInterface() {}
    virtual compare_status compare(uint8_t* start, unsigned n) = 0;
};
```

This lets you name the type (e.g. `IOBuff::compare_status`, `IOBuff::compare_status::no_match` in C++11), but it won't add the enumerations to the scope (e.g. `IOBuff::no_match` won't work).

Comment: Won't work for the enumerators. `IOBuff::no_match` :(

Comment: @n.m.: That's true. You can do `IOBuff::compare_status::no_match` though, is that good enough?

Comment: @n.m why do you need IOBuff::no_match? IOBuff is not enum

Comment: I thought it wasn't valid to fully qualify a C++03 enum (i.e., not talking about a C++11 strongly typed enum) and therefore both `compare_status::no_match` and `IOBuff::compare_status::no_match` are not valid ([Enum vs Strongly typed enum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581064/enum-vs-strongly-typed-enum)).

Comment: good idea, but I get this error: `use of enumeration in a nested name specifier is a C++11 extension`

Comment: @billz Same reason why the standard committee wanted `ios_base::end` etc.

Comment: @Claudiu in C++03 you cannot.

Comment: @n.m, why don't you just post that as an answer instead of a comment?  I would like to checkmark an answer, this will help others.