# Detect definitions of same name of enum and #define in C++ source

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, enums, redefinition

We have a C++ source with a large number of definitions made using `#define` and `enum`. Recently while analyzing a bug, we found out that there were a few definitions made using the `#define` pre-processor directive which were also members of an enum. The values assigned to them were different though.

For example,

```
#define ABC 100

typedef enum
{
  ABC = 1,
  DEF
} MY_ENUM;
```

`ABC` is defined in two places.

Amazingly, Visual Studio did not give us an error. Not even a warning.

We are worried that there might be other definitions that were defined in the same manner and want to find them out.

Increasing the warning level of the compiler did not give us any errors. We can still build the source without errors when such re-definitions are present . The number of warnings increased massively and there are too many warnings to go through one by one.

Does anyone know a way to detect these multiple definitions?

We are using Visual Studio 2010 Professional as the IDE.

Comment: This is why you shouldn't use all-uppercase for anything other than macros.

Comment: Sounds like a good moment to have a cleanup day. Replace the `#define` by `const int ABC = 100;` and Visual Studio will complain.

Answer (score 4):

Use `enum class` instead of `enum`. This way, you can make sure that you are using the right  thing in the right place

You can go through the following answers to get a better idea
[Enum vs Strongly typed enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581064/enum-vs-strongly-typed-enum)

NOTE: `enum class` is a C++11 feature and is not among those supported by Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Thanks. Even though I cannot use it if VS2010 support it, I would keep this in mind. I didn't know about enum class.

Comment: If is solves your purpose, please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3):

Even VS wouldn't compile the code you've shown. But it could do what you describe if the `#define` came *after* the `enum` definition. And if that's the case, all compilers will do exactly what you describe. The code is in no way invalid (or even warning-worthy) then.

As [@TheApache suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33625822/1782465), a C++11 solution would be to use an `enum class` instead of a plain `enum`, but that would require you to go through all use cases and add qualification. Not to mention that fact that Visual Studio 2010 doesn't support it.

Using a macro and an enumerator of the same name in a project is a *colossally **bad idea**,* so you should definitely resolve your situation by removing this condition. Ideally, you would simply remove the macro definitions and use the enumerators only.

Comment: Thanks, though if VS2010 doesn't support it, I cannot use it.

Comment: @nushydude What *I* think you should do (and what the answer says) is simply get rid of the macros altogether.