# use of enum in a constructor c++

Tags: c++, enums

I'm trying to create a class "Apple" that has two values
1. int n
2. enum color

but my code doesnt work and I get an "No matching constuctor for Initialization" Error

I don't know what is the best way to do it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdexcept>

using namespace std;

class Color{
public:
   enum color{r,g};
};

class Apple: public Color {
    int n;
    Color c;
public:
    Apple(int n,Color color){
        if(n<0)throw runtime_error("");
        this->n=n;
        this->c=color;
    }
    int n_return(){return n;}
};
int main(){
    try{
        const Apple a1{10,Color::g};
        cout << a1.n_return();}
    catch(runtime_error&){
        cout<<"ER\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I don't want to change anything in main.

Additionally, how can I set the default color of apple to g in the constructor for when there is no color given?

Comment: `Apple` inherits and contains `Color`  (which is empty class BTW) ?

Comment: Why keep enum inside of class instead of using `enum class`?

Comment: `enum class Color { red, green };`

Comment: `Color` != `Color::color`.

Comment: It makes no sense to have Apple inherit Color. Apples *have* a color but they are not colors.

Comment: A minor note: `Apple(int n,Color color){ if(n<0)throw runtime_error("");` is making me ask: why don't you take an unsigned as argument? This has the advantage to make the runtime more stable, the code simpler and self-documented.

Comment: @YSC https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Res-nonnegative

Comment: @SilvioMayolo This is one more core guideline I disagree with. Note though: this rule is about arithmethic; here we're simply storing a value we want positive. Better take an unsigned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Color c;` member in `class Apple` is referring to the `Color` base class instead of the `color` enumerator defined inside it. Having said that, from a design perspective, **you seem to be *inheriting* an Apple from a Color**. I believe what you intended for is having each `Apple` instance hold a color value. For that, you want [*composition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition), not *inheritance* -- as **an Apple *is not a* color**, it [is-a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) fruit : ) that [has-a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a) color.

Further, **`n_return()` needs to be a `const` method** for you to be able to invoke it from a `const` instance.

This is as closest to your original code that fills the points raised regarding syntax and design, so you could easily isolate the differences. `main()` stays the same:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdexcept>

using namespace std;

enum class Color{r,g};

class Apple{
    int n;
    Color c;
public:
    Apple(int n,Color color){
        if(n<0)throw runtime_error("");
        this->n=n;
        this->c=color;
    }
    int n_return() const {return n;}
};
int main(){
    try{
        const Apple a1{10,Color::g};
        cout << a1.n_return();}
    catch(runtime_error&){
        cout<<"ER\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note I've changed your `enum` to `enum class`. The general reasons for which you can [read about here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12581154/2754173).

If you want to [set the default](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments) `Color` for your `Apple` upon construction in case it isn't specified, then you can write the declaration for it like this:

```
// Apple has Color `g` by default
Apple(int n,Color color = Color::g){//...
```

So you can do this:

```
const Apple a1{10};
```

and get your `Color::g` colored apple.

Comment: and one more question : How can I set the default color of apple to g in the constructor for when there is no color given

Answer (score 2):

As the comments have already pointed out, you're making an (empty) class `Color` and defining a scoped enum within it. All of this is unnecessary cruft; all you need is the enum. Replace your class `Color` with

```
enum class Color{r,g};
```

and don't do `: public Color` in the `Apple` declaration.

Unrelated, but necessary to get your code working as written: You declare your `Apple` variable as `const` but then call a non-`const` method on it. In order to make this work, you'll need your `n_return` to look like this.

```
int n_return() const {return n;}
```

Notice the `const` keyword here, to allow the method to be used on `const` variables.